# Convert .bat file to .sh file

Tags: bash, batch-file

I have to convert the following .bat code in the .sh code

```
echo Setting Bonita Environment variable
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djava.naming.factory.initial=org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory"
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djava.naming.provider.url=jnp://localhost:1099"    
set "LOG_OPTS= -Djava.util.logging.config.file=D:\jboss-5.0.0.CR2-jdk6\jboss-5.0.0.CR2\server\default\conf\logging.properties"
set "SECURITY_OPTS= -Djava.security.auth.login.config=D:\jboss-5.0.0.CR2-jdk6\jboss-5.0.0.CR2\server\default\conf\jaas-standard.cfg"
set JAVA_OPTS= %JAVA_OPTS% %LOG_OPTS% %SECURITY_OPTS% 
echo %JAVA_OPTS%
```

Please guide me to do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo Setting Bonita Environment variable
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.naming.factory.initial=org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.naming.provider.url=jnp://localhost:1099"
LOG_OPTS="-Djava.util.logging.config.file=D:\jboss-5.0.0.CR2-jdk6\jboss-5.0.0.CR2\server\default\conf\logging.properties"
SECURITY_OPTS="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=D:\jboss-5.0.0.CR2-jdk6\jboss-5.0.0.CR2\server\default\conf\jaas-standard.cfg"
JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS}${LOG_OPTS}${SECURITY_OPTS}"
echo "$JAVA_OPTS"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a fairly simple conversion job:

- All variables of the form `%xyz%` should be replaced with `${xyz}`.
- All `set` statements should be `export`.
- Your `set "abc=xyz"` type statements should be `export abc="xyz"` (different position for quotes).
- Paths, of course, should reflect the Linux filesystem (no drives, forward slashes, different locations).
- If you want to *use* those variables once the script is finished, you need to `source` it or `.` it, not run it. Running it will create those variable in a sub-shell, not your desired shell.

Comment: In this scenario, no need for `export`, I guess

Comment: If you don't export them, they aren't made available to sub-shells.